# ci skip is not working in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-builder

Enabled ci skip on Jenkins UI and submitted a commit with `git commit -m "testing [ci skip]"` - I could see jenkins is still building. Could you please let me know how to skip jenkins build with ci skip in commit message. Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you only installed CI Skip in Jenkins and did not do any config changes then you should be aware that **you'll need to configure your project's Build Environment to enable CI Skip**.

Comment: I have written wrapper for this in my JJB script. I could see enable CI skip is checked in Jenkins UI page.    
 `   wrappers:
        - timestamps
        - ssh-agent-credentials:
            users:
                - '{ssh-credentials}'
        - ci-skip
        - mask-passwords  `

Comment: CI SKIP in jenkins is not working.. I am still searching for an answer to this question.. I am waiting for Jenkins team to respond on Jenkins JIRA ticket but haven't heard any thing back from them from past 1 month..

Comment: @RBT: what version control system are you using? I had to patch the code to make it work with Mercurial, but asides from that everything now works as expected.

Comment: I am using github as Version control system.. I could see Build is triggered and failed.. As per plugin details, when I use ci skip in commit message, Jenkins should not trigger a build. IT should work like in Travis.  Below is the log details.                                                                                                 ```fix broken link in readme
 [ci skip]
Setting status of e2742998080844a437d49e9f7de7ad2044f38471 to FAILURE with url <some url> and message: 'Build failed
Using context: jenkins/x86_64
Finished: NOT_BUILT ```

Answer (score 0):

**jenkins GitLabPushTrigger** 
**[ci-skip]**

```
git commit -m"[ci-skip] you comment"
```

https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/blob/c27af273327e1660d619a27045f0dd301af68067/src/main/java/com/dabsquared/gitlabjenkins/trigger/handler/push/PushHookTriggerHandlerImpl.java#L32-L35

```
protected boolean isCiSkip(PushHook hook) {
    List<Commit> commits = hook.getCommits();
    return commits != null && !commits.isEmpty() && commits.get(0).getMessage() != null && commits.get(0).getMessage().contains("[ci-skip]");
}
```